# String concatenation does not work properly in Java when concatenating 2 results of ternary operators

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

Dear Java guru 's!

Can you, please, explain me, why String concatenation does not work properly in Java when concatenating 2 results of ternary operators?

Example:

```
String str = null;
String x = str != null ? "A" : "B" + str == null ? "C" : "D";
System.out.println(x);
```

Output is "D", but I expected "BC".

I am suspecting that it works like so because of operators priorities, but I am not sure, about how we exactly we get "D" for case above. What calculation algorithm takes place for this case?

Comment: The precedence isn't what you expected. When in doubt, add parentheses.

Comment: I feel like this is a case where ternaries reduce readability.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am currently mentoring an appropriate [issue in Checkstyle sandbox](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/issues/167). In this issue we want to let others prevent such unreadable ternary-based expressions in their code by using Checkstyle

Comment: In fact, code like this is what gives ternaries a bad name and makes people come up with too-broad rules like "never use the ternary operator."

Comment: Why never? I think it is better to let people decide what count of ternaries could be allowed per one expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's interpreted as following code:

```
String x = str != null ? "A" : ("B" + str == null ? "C" : "D");
```

`"B" + str` is not null so it will be evaluated as `"D"`

With help of OSborn's answer you can do what you expect with this code:

```
String x = (str != null ? "A" : "B") + (str == null ? "C" : "D");
```

and since you are just comparing `str` with `null` and both conditional statements are almost the same, it can be shortened like this:

```
 String x = (str != null ? "AD" : "BC");
```

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much! Linked this answer with [related issue in Checkstyle sandbox](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/issues/167) as best explanation

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the order of operations. You can make it explicit by writing:

```
String x = (str != null ? "A" : "B") + (str == null ? "C" : "D");
```

Answer (score 1):

`"B" + str == null ? "C"`, String concatenation evaliated first before the conditional expression evaluated

Answer (score 1):

I think you intended

```
String x = (str != null ? "A" : "B") + (str == null ? "C" : "D");
```